# Странное поведение .bind в jquery

Tags: jquery

Добрый день.

Пытаюсь написать плагин на для jquery, который бы находил специально отмеченные div-ы и вставлял в них html-код.
Свежесозданные элементы должны реагировать на событие click:

```
$('button[data-type="site"]').bind("click", function (e) {console.log(e,$(this));});
```

На странице находятся 2 элемента, которые обрабатываются плагином:

```
$('div[data-type="placeholder"]').myPlugin();
```

Странность (для меня) в том, что при нажатии на первую кнопку я получаю в консоли 2 вывода сonsole.log, а при нажатии на вторую кнопку - один (что является правильным поведением).

Почему задваивается вызов функции -обработчика события?

Пример тут http://test.controlcash.ru/b.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего странного, вы выбираете кнопку селектором, и происходит следующее

- создать **кнопку**
- повесить событие на **кнопку** `// тут кнопка одна на нее вешаем обработчик`
- создать **кнопку**
- повесить событие на **кнопку** `// а тут кнопки две, вешаем еще раз на первую и на новую`

чтобы победить нужно то что у вас получается в res3 превратить в объект jQuery и уже на него вешать обработчик:

```
$button = $(res_3).appendTo(this.$element);
/...../
$button.on('click',function(){
   /......./
});
```

не забудте объявить `$button` где нить выше.

Comment: кстати, replace вы можете вызывать так

    string.replace().replace().replace();

и не забывайте писать var!

Comment: Супер! Спасибо! Тогда и селектор на кнопку не нужен.

Comment: 2eicto : да, в итоге я так replace и переписал.